# Why doesn't NFS recognize a new UID?

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I have two servers running RHEL6. I have **root** access to both. The main server, which I will refer to as `server`, is a database server. The application server, which I will refer to as `client`, mounts a directory from `server` via NFS.

There is a user, `appuser`, on both `client` and `server`. However, `appuser`'s UID on `client` is `502`. `appuser`'s UID on `server` is `506`.

Both users need read and write capability on the NFS share. To facilitate this, I made the share owned by `appuser` on `server`.

Running `id appuser` on each yields: `uid=506(appuser)`.

Of course, `client` does not recognize that ownership, since `appuser` has a different id on `client`. So I did the following:

- Changed UID of user in /etc/passwd on `client` to be 506.
- Changed ownership of `appuser`'s $HOME on `client` to be `appuser` again so that I could log in.

Now, when I go to look at the NFS share from the `client` side, I see that it is owned by `502`. `502` is the OLD id for `appuser` on client. I can't change ownership of the NFS share from `client`, since that is a volume that physically resides on `server`.

I need to make sure that the NFS share shows ownership of `appuser` from both `server` and `client`.

What step have I missed since changing the `appuser` id on client?

**NOTE**: I have not rebooted `client` (or anything else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I have got it. Found it on Bing after trying many times. Still not certain exactly WHICH thing fixed by problem, of two possibilities. But here they are.

There is "tell" on the internet that there can be client ownership permission problems with NFS v4. I don't know if that's true, and I don't care. Somebody had something they called a solution. So I followed the instructions to force the client to mount the drive as NFS version 3. So the first thing I did was change my mount line permissions in /etc/fstab from this:

```
rw,hard,intr
```

to this:

```
rw,hard,intr,vers=3
```

Also, I started the nfs daemon on the client, just because someone said to do it:

```
service nfs start
```

Then, because I was following some dated instructions, I checked to see if the `portmap` service was running on the client:

```
service portmap status
```

and was greeted with:

```
portmap: unrecognized service
```

Then I found that `portmap` is now rolled into `rpcbind`. So:

```
service rpcbind status
```

And I saw:

```
rpcbind dead but pid file exists
```

Then:

```
[root@myserver customers]# service rpcbind restart
Stopping rpcbind:                                          [FAILED]
Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
```

Then I checked the ownership of the NFS share, and it was CORRECT!

Answer (score 3):

`id appuser` will likely show you that the shell still sees the old UID for the user.  Logout and log back in.

Comment: They are both showing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

File ownership is saved with user ids. When you were looking at those files and seeing them as owned by `appuser` before the 502 -> 506 change, they were actually owned by user id 502 (`ls -n` will confirm). This has not changed.

Therefore, if you want to see `appuser` as the owner, you will have to change the ownership of the files from 502 to 506. And you may have to do that **on the server** if you do not have permissions on the client.

How to change the permissions is a different topic. If you do not have access to the server you can try copying the files using your new user (assuming you have read only access) and removing them later. It may be easier if you temporarily create a user with id 502 which will be able to change the permissions (but not the ownership) of the files owned by 502, rename them, or remove them after you copy them.

Comment: This is not correct. The ownership of `506` on the `server` is correct, it is being mapped to `502` by NFS on the client. Restarting `client` fixed this problem for me, although there may be a less heavy-weight way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on solaris 11.

systema : zfs filesystem shared to systemB - files owned by userid davida UID 305
systemb : filesystem mounted from systemA - created local user davida with UID 304

permissions on nfs shared directories was 755, files was 700. davida UID 304 on systemb could not open files.

changed UID of davida on systemB to 305

Umounted nfs filesystem and changed user id davida on systemB to UID to 305 to match systemA.

Remounted nfs filesystem. Files still shows owner as UID 304

why ???